# How many ways of a cup frozen yogurt can be dressed up?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> Three of $16$ toppings can be selected for dressing up a cup of frozen yogurt.  How many ways of a cup of frozen yogurt can be dressed up?
>
> Select one:
>
> a. $3360$
>
> b. $560$
>
> c. $48$
>
> d. $45$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: $42$. Also, what does this have to do with [tag:sequences-and-series]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: this is assuming that the order does matter*

You have $16$ possible toppings that can be selected and you can only select $3$.

When you pick your first topping, you will have $16$ options.

As you have already chosen $1$ out of these $16$ toppings, when you pick your second topping, you will have one less  option, i.e. your second topping will have $15$ options.

With this same logic, you have $14$ options for your last topping choice.

The total number of ways is given by: $16 × 15 × 14 = 3360$ options.

If order doesn't matter (i.e. combinations), then the answer is simply $16C3 = 560$ ways.

Comment: You should specify that you are assuming that the order of the toppings matters, which is not clear from the question.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig - true...so perhaps $16C3$ = $560$ is an alternative answer.

Comment: Agreed.  That said, you should specify that the answer would be $3360$ if the order of the toppings matters and that the answer would be $560$ if the order of the toppings does not matter.  I believe the latter interpretation was intended, but the question could have made that assumption more explicit.